# Is there any way to add a column to the food tracker to show Weight Watchers points?

Tags: fitbit

I'm new to Fitbit web app. I am loving it so far, but because I am coming from Weight Watchers I'd like to see those points as well while I transition to calorie counting instead.

Maybe there is a Greasemonkey script, or a setting to add custom fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a solution for myself via Chrome Extension.
[Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ebbbealeoenkoenmhhjinpnnlmoeobnp)

This is my first chrome extension, and this is not intended to publicize said extension.  I may create Firefox and Safari versions at a later date, but as this is currently for my personal use and I use Chrome here it is.

I will also include the code here for anyone interested in modifying or adding to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dailyTotal = 0;
//Update header name
$("#loggedFoodArea .subheader .cols7").html('PS');
//Loop through the listings and calculate points
$('#loggedFoodArea .listing ul li').each(function(index) {
    var cals = $(this).children('.cols3').html();
    var fat = $(this).children('.cols4').html();
    var fiber = $(this).children('.cols5').html();
    var ps = ((cals/50)+(fat/12)-(fiber/4)).toFixed(1);
    dailyTotal += parseFloat(ps);
    $(this).children('.cols7').html(ps);
});
$('#dailyTotals .content .total').last().after('<div class="total" style="margin-left: 12px;"><div class="label"><div class="substance">Points</div><div class="amount"><span id="pointAmount">'+(parseFloat(dailyTotal)/2).toFixed(1)+'</span></div></div></div>');
```

});

Comment: If anyone objects, and feels I did this in interest of self promotion, please speak up and I will delete the entire post.